# How to set the dropdown display default to "Medium" and not to be "High"?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

Code:

```
public enum PriorityEnum
{
    High,
    Medium,
    Low
}

IQueryable<PriorityValues> priorityValues = _enumReadService.GetRecords<PriorityValues>();

var creationOptions = new CreationOptions
{
    PriorityValues = priorityValues.ToList()
};
```

I am getting the dropdown displaying default to **"High"**. But **it needs** to be **"Medium"**. How to set the dropdown display default to "Medium" and not to be "High"?

**Update: Adding the rendering dropdown code**

```
<b>@Html.Label("Priority:")</b>
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PriorityValueId, Enum.GetValues(typeof (PriorityValueEnum)).OfType<PriorityValueEnum>().ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem {Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int) x).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown how you rendered the DropDown, but if you used the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Priority, Model.PriorityValues)
```

all you need to do is set the value of the `Priority` property in the controller action to the desired result:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> priorityValues = ...
model.PriorityValues = priorityValues;
model.Priority = (int)PriorityEnum.Medium;
return View(model);
```

Comment: I have updated my question by adding the rendering code. How to set  the dropdown display be default to "Medium"? Thanks.

Comment: As shown in my answer, in your controller action you should set the `PriorityValueId` to the desired value in your controller action: `model.PriorityValueId = (int)PriorityEnum.Medium;`

Comment: Thanks, Working Fine as expected.